# How to calculate the probability density function of this random variable?

Tags: probability

I am reading the book by Sergio Verdu [Multiuser Detection](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=521411). In page 39, equation (2.36) and (2.37) are given as follow:
$$\bar{\rho}_{kj}=\langle\bar{s}_k,\bar{s}_j\rangle=\rho_{kj}\cos(\phi_{k}-\phi_{j}).\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2.36)$$

> "Because the phases $\phi_k$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $[0, 2\pi]$, the probability density function of $\bar{\rho}_{kj}$ is given by"

$$f_{\bar{\rho}_{kj}}(r)=\dfrac{1}{\pi\sqrt{\rho_{kj}^2-r^2}},\quad r\in(-\rho_{kj},\rho_{kj}).\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2.37)$$

My question is: how to get the pdf in equation (2.37)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\phi_j$ and $\phi_k$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$, then the difference $\Theta:=\phi_k-\phi_j$ will have a triangular distribution from $-2\pi$ to $2\pi$. However, as far as cosine is concerned, we can restrict the difference to the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ (or any other interval of length $2\pi$), by adding or subtracting $2\pi$ as needed. When restricted in this way, the difference $\Theta$ will have a uniform distribution. (It might help to draw a picture to see how the triangular density becomes uniform.)

Now if $\Theta$ is a uniform$[-\pi,\pi]$ variable, then $R:=\cos\Theta$ has density
$$f_R(r)=\frac1{\pi\sqrt{1-r^2}},\qquad\text{$|r|<1$.}$$
(See [this link](http://www.ece.unm.edu/faculty/bsanthan/ece340/transrv.pdf) for a proof.) The density of $aR$ is then
$$
f_{aR}(r)=\frac1af_R(r/a)= \frac1{\pi\sqrt{a^2-r^2}},\qquad\text{$|r|<a$}.
$$